# Grails gorm 'where' query with 'lower()' and 'in' operator

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-3.0

I have a Domain class

```
class Hashtag {
    String tag
}
```

Why

```
Hashtag.where { lower(tag) == "#london" }.list()
```

works ok, but

```
Hashtag.where { lower(tag) in [ "#london", "#paris" ] }.list()
```

results in

`org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Unsupported function [lower] defined in query for property [hashtag] with type [class java.lang.String]`

How to write such query properly?

Thanks!

Comment: I have similar code that uses the lower() method, and have noticed that it works inconsistently. When it doesn't work the workaround is to re-deploy the war file to the tomcat instance. Instead I'll use your createCriteria() method below to see if it works more consistently.

Comment: Can't say about consistency. I use lower() method, but I do not keep an eye on how does it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't answer why using `lower()` with `in()` did not work. I read the [source](https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/fd60354d1b25f259dbc7b5def7a4ad1d615a0ddc/grails-datastore-gorm/src/main/groovy/org/grails/datastore/gorm/query/transform/DetachedCriteriaTransformer.java) but I don't know ASTs well enough to understand it.

But, to solve your problem you can use a [derived property](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/GORM.html#derivedProperties) to perform the `lower()`.

```
class Hashtag {
    String tag
    String loweredTag

    static mapping {
        loweredTag formula: 'lower(tag)'
    }
}
```

Then you can use the derived property in the where query:

```
Hashtag.where { loweredTag in [ "#london", "#paris" ] }.list()
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, I've found alternative way to do case-insensitive comparison - using Criteria. An advantage of this method is that values in `cities` also could be mixed cases.

```
def cities = ["#LONdon", "#PAris"]
Hashtag.createCriteria().list {
    or {
        cities.each { eq("tag", it, [ignoreCase: true])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will work as per your need.
But [documentation](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/GORM.html#querying) says that you may use subqueries in where block like below:

```
Hashtag.where { lower(tag).of{} in [ "#london", "#paris" ] }.list()
```

Please try it and let me know if it doesn't work.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work, resulting in
```groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria.lower() is applicable for argument types: (grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria) values: [grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria@3a76c384]
Possible solutions: toSet(), or(groovy.lang.Closure), order(java.lang.String), count(), get(), list()```